# Caesar Cipher with Ascii Characters

Tags: java, ascii

I'm trying to encrypt a String using ascii characters with a key position integer. I've got two methods, one for encrypting, one for decrypting.

The problem is that when the character value is above 126, I try to mod 126 it and then add 32 back into it but I get numbers far out of these limits.

```
public static String encrypt(String s, int k) {
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    int ascii;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        ascii = (int) arr[i];
        ascii = ascii + k;
        // System.out.println(ascii);
        if (ascii > 126) {
            ascii = 32 + (126 % ascii);
            // System.out.print("Changed: " + ascii);
        }

        arr[i] = (char) ascii;
    }
    return String.valueOf(arr);
}
```

The two commented out lines were for testing, and the changed values are crazy high, like instead of going from 127 % 126 = 1 + 32 for a total of 33 (intended value), I get 15870.

Comment: Consider providing sample inputs and expected/current outputs

Comment: There are over 100 current Caesar Cipher questions with answers and most consist of the same problem, not understanding ASCII encoding and/or the modulus (%) operator. Read them, study them, debug your code, you can use a debugger or go caveman with print statements.

Answer (score 2):

First, as mypetlion mentioned, the modulo operation a % b equals the remainder when a is divided by b. E.g. 11 % 4 = 3, 8 % 15 = 8. To be precise, it is the value k that satisfies b * n + k = a, b * (n + 1) > a, k < b where n is an integer. There are more appropriate descriptions using discrete maths and I'm ignoring negative arguments but they are not important. So in your case you should be doing ascii % 128.

As of why the modulo should be 128 and not 126, 7 bit ascii code goes from 0-127, 128 values in total. Also I'm a bit confused as to what the +32 is for, since you already did +k.

Also you can omit your if block completely because c % 128 = c for any c in range [0, 128).

So I would write the following code:

```
public static String encrypt(String s, int k) {
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = (char) ((arr[i] + k) % 128);
    }
    return String.valueOf(arr);
}
public static String decrypt(String s, int k) {
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = (char) ((arr[i] + 128 - k % 128) % 128);
        // + 128 - k % 128 because I don't want do deal with negative numbers.
    }
    return String.valueOf(arr);
}
```

I am confident my code will work (for all positive values of k), but I cannot explain why your code produced some crazy high ascii values. When I ran your code on my IDE it didn't do that nor could I see why it would from your code.

Finally, this cipher method will encrypt and decrypt alright, but note that ascii does contain lots of control characters that are not print-friendly. So if you want to limit your cipher vocabulary to only letters and punctuations, you would need to do some character mapping to limit the characters you want to encrypt and encrypt to. This will be much more complicated, not to mention that you would have to consider problems like CR+LF in Windows v. LF in Unix. The following is a simple example that only encrypts and decrypts letters.

```
public static int asciiToCustom(char ascii) {
// Maps 65-90 & 97-122 to 0-51.
    int customCode;
    if(ascii >= 65 && ascii <= 90){
        customCode = ascii - 65;
    }
    else if(ascii >= 97 && ascii <= 122){
        customCode = ascii - 71;
    }
    else{
        throw new RuntimeException("not a letter!");
    }
    return customCode;
}
public static char customToAscii(int custom) {
// Maps 0-51 to 65-90 & 97-122.
    int ascii;
    if(custom >= 0 && custom <= 25){
        ascii = custom + 65;
    }
    else if(custom >= 26 && custom <= 51){
        ascii = custom + 71;
    }
    else{
        throw new RuntimeException("not a valid custom code!");
    }
    return (char) ascii;
}
public static String encrypt(String s, int k) {
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(Character.isLetter(arr[i])){
            arr[i] = customToAscii((asciiToCustom(arr[i]) + k) % 52);
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(arr);
}
public static String decrypt(String s, int k) {
    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(Character.isLetter(arr[i])){
            arr[i] = customToAscii((asciiToCustom(arr[i]) + 52 - k % 52) % 52);
            // + 52 - k % 52 because I don't want do deal with negative numbers.
        }
    }
    return String.valueOf(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your modulo statement is written backwards for a start. Try:

```
ascii = 32 + (ascii % 126);
```

Comment: Changed! I've tried it both ways, one gives me 15870, the other gives me 3370

Comment: Your second print statement is a `print` not a `println`. Are you sure that 70 isn't just the next value in the array?